# Run a short cut with a "program1.exe" -vm "program2.exe"

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch script which I run when I start my computer. It runs all the programs I need for the day with the current format of:

```
start  "outlook" "C:\Program Files (x86)\MicrosoftOffice\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE"
```

However, I can't seem to get a program shortcut to run.

It uses this as its target:

```
"program1.exe" -vm "program2.exe"
```

I have tried:

```
start "program" "program1.exe" -vm "program2.exe"

start "program" "program1.exe" parameters -vm "program2.exe"

start "program" /b "C:\directory\shortcut.lnk
```

…and just running them both seperately:

```
start /wait "program1" "program1.exe"
start "program2" "program2.exe"
```

Comment: I would try rearranging or escaping the quotes, so that the `start` command receives a single command line argument.

Comment: I would suggest you provide the full and exact shortcut target content, _unless of course it's a national secret!_